# sum values which are loaded in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I plus all values of one selected row of a gridview in C# asp.net application?
For example I have a gridview in which is only one row. Values of this row are only number. So I want to plus this numbers.

I tried this loop but it  writes all gridview numbers(it isn't summing them).

```
for (int i = 2; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
       int x = 0;
       x += int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text);
       Response.Write(x.ToString());                    
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean.  Can you include an example?  Are you trying to modify just the display, or maybe persist updated values to a data store?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @user2971569 What you have tried please add .aspx and .cs code here?

Comment: int i = 2;
        int x = 0;
        do
        {
            
                x = x + int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text);
                i++;
            
            
        } while (i <= GridView1.Columns.Count);

Comment: I tried loop too but it doesn't work

Comment: I added in my question thing that I tried

Comment: you are setting x to 0 and then printing x in your loop, set x before the loop and print the total after the loop.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thankshttp N4TKD !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should approach this from a different perspective.  The `GridView` is just a display control and doesn't 'hold' the data it is displaying.  You are trying to use data that it really doesn't contain using a 'screen scrape' approach. You should be looking to the `DataSource` you bound to the grid in the first place and using the data there.

For example:

```
List<YourObjectWithTheNumbers> lst = something;
yourGridView.DataSource = lst;
ViewState["YourData"] = lst;  // you could use Session instead: Session["YourData"]
```

So at this point your data is bound and saved for later use so now just update your numbers and rebind to the `GridView` again:

```
List<YourObjectWithTheNumbers> lst =
    (List<YourObjectWithTheNumbers>)(ViewState["YourData"]);
int rowTotal = 0;
rowTotal += lst[0].Field1;
rowTotal += lst[0].Field2;
//etc...
yourLiteral.Text = rowTotal.ToString();
```

At this point you are using the actual data, not pulling it out of the grid that should be used for display purposes.  It's also more secure in that you can keep the data source securely stored on the server if necessary (don't use `ViewState` if this is a concern) so that it can't be manipulated.

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first, too.  The downside is that this takes a post-back to the server.  If the original post was only concerned about displaying the sum to the webpage, then javascript is a more practical answer, as others have mentioned.  Unfortunately, the original question didn't go into that.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML GridView render as table , better you can use Jquery to add the values ,

```
var total=0;
$('#gridview1').find('tr td').each(function(i, td){ 
            var data= parseInt( $(td).val()); 
            total+=data;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I created method in which I had loop and it worked !!!!!!!

```
public int Sum()
{
    int z = 0;
    int i;
    int x = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {

        x += int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text);

    }
return x;
}
```

It was @N4TKD idea. Thanks to you !!!!